# How to update particular column multiple rows with subquery

Tags: mysql

please help mi relating to following mysql query,
I have a table main with like below:

```
id      phone                phone2 
======================================
1       98998 | 58877
2       98998 | 58877
3       98998
```

i want to update phone2 through phone column and trying to used following subquery but i didnt got the desired result please help to got the result if it is possible:

```
update main a 
set a.phone2 = (SELECT substring_index(b.phone,'|',-1) 
                FROM main b 
where b.phone like '%|%' and where a.id=b.id)
```

Comment: It seems that you have two numbers in coloumn phone seperated by "|". Are you trying to seperate two numbers, keeping one in phone and other in phone2. Editing with sample/example will help in understanding question.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
UPDATE main a 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT id, substring_index(phone,'|',-1) AS phone
                FROM main 
                WHERE phone LIKE '%|%' 
        ) b
        ON a.id = b.id
SET a.phone2 = b.phone;
```